# Mysql restart auto int primary key

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, auto-increment

Hello is it possible to save the deleted auto incremented primary key in my database. For example

I have
Name_ID

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

If I delete primary key 4 and I insert again the primary key of I inserted should be four.

so. Name 1 2 3 4 5

---

I deleted primary key 5 (Name 1 2 3 4)

---

I added a data primary key should be 5 again not 6. THANKS!

Comment: Why you want an *auto* increment field if you don't want to auto increment it? What you want to happen if you delete, say, the key number 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto generated fields always have gaps in these cases.

What if you have an audit or history table that stored the rows with ID = 4, ID = 5? Then delete them again? How do you differentiate rows?

In your example, you've only deleted the last row? What is you delete ID = 1? Then what?

That is, they are just internal numbers unique to that table (and any associated tables like audit ones): no external meaning should be attached

Comment: Thanks! I'll not use this method then seeing the disadvantages. :))

Comment: @rjtubera:  The gaps with autoincrement fields are standard and expected behaviour: not disadvantages. "Rolling your own" will have more disadvantages and end in tears

Answer (score 2):

As with other comments and answers here, I would not recommend this, especially if the data in the auto increment column is referenced externally, but you can set the next auto increment number to a specific value via an `ALTER TABLE` query

```
ALTER TABLE T_YourTable AUTO_INCREMENT=4
```

You could also drop the column and then re-add the column with the same attributes (this could be expensive if you have a lot of rows).

Answer (score 0):

Why?

It's only intended to be a unique identifier.

You'll also get gaps with database clusters and whenever you rollback an insert transaction which overlaps a commited transaction - not just when you delete data.

A mechanism to fill-in-the-gaps would be complex, slow and difficult to maintain - and it's not needed.